# Writing the integral of f(x) without any variables to find C.

Tags: integration, functions

I was given the equation $f(t) = 2t+3$ with an interval of [-3, 6], and I'm told to write a function for F(t) where $F(x) = \int_3^xf(t)dt$. Knowing integration I understand that the anti-derivative is $t^2+3t+C$ but I don't know what C is, and I need that for the answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need $C$ for the answer?  You evaluate at upper and lower limits and subtract so...

Comment: I need C because the answers I am given are equations, and they both contain a C, one has a C of 54, the other of -18.

Comment: But.... $G'(t)=f(t)\implies \int_b^a f(t)dt=G(a)-G(b)$.  Thus, in your case, $F(x)=x^2+3x+C-(3^2+3*3+C)=x^2+3x-18$.  The $C$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

You know the family of antiderivatives for $f$ are $t^2 + 3t+C$, but the condition that $F$ records the area below $f$ relative to $x=3$ actually uniquely specifies $C$. In particular you know $$F(3) = \int_3^3 f(t) \, dt = 0$$ and so $3^2 + 3\cdot 3 + C = 0$, hence $C  = -18$.

Answer (score 2):

$$F(x) = \int_3^xf(t)dt = \left [ t^2+3t+C\right ]_{t=3}^{x} = x^2 + 3x + C - 3^2 -3\cdot 3 - C = x^2 + 3x   -18 $$